# calling react setState multiple times in mount

Tags: reactjs, axios, logic

Having trouble understanding best practice for mounting Components using setState in React. I have an app that returns the starter pokemon of each generation of pokemon. Each generation has its own axios.get() method that iterates over 8 items. I want to store those 8 items in an array pertaining to that generation:

```
class Pokedex extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            pokedex: [
                { index: 1, generation: 1, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 152, generation: 2, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 252, generation: 3, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 387, generation: 4, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 495, generation: 5, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 650, generation: 6, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 722, generation: 7, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 810, generation: 8, pokemon: [] }
            ]
        }
    }
    fetchPokemon(index){
        for(var i=index; i<=index+8; i++){
            axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
            .then((res) => {
                return res.data.name;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.state.pokedex.forEach(i => { 
                this.fetchPokemon(i.index)
         });
    }
    render(){
        return()
    }
}

export default Pokedex
```

How can I use setState to save the results of each `this.fetchPokemon(index)`  iteration to the state.pokedex Object it pertains to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid Immutable Data Structures

Immutable data allow direct use of memory reference and require less process.

We have a common problem using immutable data, trying to compare changes in variables that don't have the same reference.

If some change was made directly in the props, we can't compare like this:

```
React.memo(SomeComp, (props, nextProps) => {
 if (props.prop1 === nextProps.prop1) {
   return true;
 }
});
```

Example:

```
let neymar = { "name": "Neymar", "score": 1 }
neymar.score = 2
console.log(neymar)
 
 
const mbappe = { "name": "mbappe", "score": 0 }
const updateMbappe = {...mbappe, score: 4};
 
console.log(updateMbappe)
```

Try something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const pokemonList = [
    { index: 1, generation: 1, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 152, generation: 2, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 252, generation: 3, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 387, generation: 4, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 495, generation: 5, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 650, generation: 6, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 722, generation: 7, pokemon: [] },
    { index: 810, generation: 8, pokemon: [] }
];

const fetchPokemon = (index) => {
    const fillPokemonList = [];
    for(var i=index; i<=index+8; i++){
        axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
        .then((res) => {
            fillPokemonList.push(res.data.name);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    return fillPokemonList;
}


class Pokedex extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            pokedex: pokemonList
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getPokemons()
    }

    getPokemons() {
        const copyList = this.state.pokedex;
        copyList.forEach(i => {
            i.pokemon.push(fetchPokemon(i.index))
        });
        this.setState(copyList)
    }

  render() {
    return()
  }
}

export default Pokedex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() { // has to be UNSAFE as you are changing state on mount
    let pokedexKeys = Object.keys(this.state.pokedex); // getting all keys in a list
    pokedexKeys.forEach((pokeKey) => { // looping through keys
      this.setState((prev) => ({
        pokedex: {
          ...prev.pokedex, // writing previous state
          [pokeKey]: { // overwriting object with current key
            ...this.state.pokedex[pokeKey], // taking previous values
            pokemon: this.fetchPokemon(pokeKey), // fetching data
          },
        },
      }));
    });
  }
```

And changing your state from:

```
{
            pokedex: [
                { index: 1, generation: 1, pokemon: [] },
                { index: 152, generation: 2, pokemon: [] },
                ....
            ]
}
```

To:

```
{
            pokedex: { // changing it from list to object
                1: {generation: 1, pokemon: [] }, // with index as key
                152: {generation: 2, pokemon: [] },
                ....
            }
}
```

So this isn't the best way of doing it, but may work...

Comment: I like this approach but noticed React recommends avoiding UNSAFE_componentWillMount